# Laravel Eloquent Query to Check Overlapping Start and End DateTime Fields

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, time, eloquent

I am trying to create a booking system where a user selects a start date and time. The system creates an end date and time based on the longest product service time. This is currently all figured out.

I have a table in my database for my events that has:

```
vendor_id | user_id | start | end
```

The start and end columns are of type DateTime.

In my controller i'm trying to find out if a particular date and time is available, but for some reason I can't get it to show me items where the times overlap.

Here is my controller code:

```
$items = $query->where('vendor_id', $user->vendor->id)->where('start', '<=', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($start)))->whereDate('end', '>=', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($end)))->get();
```

So a few example scenarios...

I have an event in the system that has a start of ***2019-01-01 13:00:00*** and an end time of ***2019-01-01 17:00:00***.

If I choose a start time of 2019-01-01 12:00:00 and an end time of 2019-01-01 16:00:00 then it passes my check above, but those times clearly overlap for several hours.

I'm trying to find a solution to pull items even if they overlap, not JUST if their start and end times meet a certain check.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't fully understand your question but will attempt to answer it anyway. For date overlaps I see four scenarios where an overlap would occur. Consider A as your event time span and B as the search param time span

```
1)
   A1          A2
B1       B2


2)
   A1          A2
         B1       B2


3)
   A1          A2
B1                B2


4)
   A1          A2
       B1  B2
```

Translated to comparison it would be

- 1) B1 < A1 AND B2 > A1
- 2) B1 > A1 AND B1 < A2
- 3) B1 < A1 AND B2 > A1
- 4) B1 > A1 AND B1 < A2

1,3 are the same as well as 2,4

And in laravel this should suffice

```
$query->where(function ($query) {
    $query->where([
        [$B1, '<', $A1],
        [$B2, '>', $A1],
    ])->orWhere([
        [$B1, '>', $A1],
        [$B1, '<', $A2],
    ]);
});
```

As an sql statement this would be

```
where (($B1 < $A1 and $B2 > $A1) or ($B1 > $A1 and $B1 < $A2))
```

Comment: You could probably refine the query with `whereBetween` and other stuff, also, I recommend using Carbon for handling dates, besides the fact that table fields cast as dates in laravel being instantiated as Carbon objects, Carbon have some neat functionality..

Comment: That worked. Sometimes another perspective is all you need. Haha. Thanks.

Comment: Good deal, glad I could help. Fiddling with dates and periods is always fun :)

Comment: Or just check that one is strictly before or after the other. Right?
IF B2  < A1  then, All of B was before A. They don't overlap.
IF B1 > A2 then, All of B was after A. They don't overlap.
so "where NOT ( B2 < A1 or B1 > A2)" should get overlap.

Sadly, whereNot doesn't exist in Laravel.